# Convert dates in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

This question is based on my old question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66263944/transform-date-format-inside-csv-using-apache-nifi).

I used solution with custom `CSVReader` and `CSVRecordSetWriter` services. A few days ago I noticed that field with date can contains invalid date format, for example instead of date `1/29/2020 3:00:00 AM` there can be a value `0`. So, `UpdateRecord` processor can't parse this csv:

```
AdvertiserID,CampaignStartDate,CampaignEndDate,CampaignName
10730729,1/29/2020 3:00:00 AM,2/20/2020 3:00:00 AM,Nestle
40376079,0,4/1/2020 3:00:00 AM,Heinz
...
```

I decided to use `UpdateRecord` without custom `CSV` services and update date format like this:

```
/CampaignStartDate ${field.value:equals('0'):ifElse('null', ${field.value:toDate("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"):format("yyyy-MM-dd"))}
```

So, I want to put `if-else` logic into `UpdateRecord` processor. But I met two problems:

1. It writes `null` as string, but it should be `null` as data type.
2. It writes `${field.value:toDate("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"):format("yyyy-MM-dd"))` as field value

Result is:

```
AdvertiserID,CampaignStartDate,CampaignEndDate,CampaignName
10730729,${field.value:toDate("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"):format("yyyy-MM-dd")),2/20/2020 3:00:00 AM,Nestle
40376079,null,4/1/2020 3:00:00 AM,Heinz
...
```

How can I implement if/else logic in Apache NiFi for this case?

**Update**

I solved problem #2:

```
${field.value:equals('0')
 :ifElse(
         'null',
         ${field.value:replace(${field.value},${field.value:toDate('M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'):format('yyyy-MM-dd')})}
)}
```

But problem #1 is still here. Because I can't save `null` (it writes as String) to database column with `date` type. It returns:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "null" Where: COPY null_place_report_8246a29a_f620_4333_97f5_e47, row 62, column campaign_start_date: "null"
```

**Update #2**

Fixed problem #1. Changed expression to:

```
${field.value:equals('0')
 :ifElse(
         '',
         ${field.value:replace(${field.value},${field.value:toDate('M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'):format('yyyy-MM-dd')})}
)}
```

And Reader defines it as null by itself.

Anyway, other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
${field.value:equals('0')
 :ifElse(
         '',
         ${field.value:replace(
            ${field.value},${field.value:toDate('M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'):format('yyyy-MM-dd')}
          )}
)}
```